# How do i replicate 10060 ( WSAETIMEDOUT ) error in c++ socket programming?

Tags: c++

In Socket programming, i am getting an error 10060 while sending data using **WSASend**, Can anyone help to replicate the error in code.This error occurs after 3 or more hours of continuous sending of data.

Comment: Is the socket blocking or non-blocking? Does the receiver keep up with reading all data?

Comment: It is blocking socket.Yes, receiver is reading all the data without any delays.

Comment: Have you made sure that programs on host and client are running correctly? No deadlock, hangups or crashes there? To diagnose the error, you should add log-messages to your code in the appropriate places to see at which point one of the parties does not react anymore.

Comment: @ Bjorn, yes there are no hang or crashed in server and client. I have logged everywhere. I am getting 10060 afterthe usage of 3+ hours.3+hours it works fine but afterwards it is giving 10060 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the socket is blocking, `WSASend` should only be returning with error `WSAETIMEDOUT` is you have set a timeout using `setsockopt` with `SO_SNDTIMEO`.

The error means that the receiving computer haven't replied within the timeout set.